# Filter Content via multiple Dropdown Lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have 2 dropdown lists and they filter the content separately. If the selected option is in the div, the div is displayed.

How can I filter the content using both of them together ? All I want is to have these 2 dropdown lists work together. Individually they are filtering the content at the moment. So, if dropdown list 1 filters the content ABCDE individually and dropdown list 2 filters the content DEG if both of them are selected, the content displayed should be DE

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#level').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if ( val == '00'){
      $(".textIc").show();
    }else{
      $('.textIc').each(function(){
        if($(this).children("p").text().indexOf(val) !==-1){
          $(this).show();
        }else{
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $('#type').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if ( val == '000'){
      $(".textIc").show();
    }else{
      $('.textIc').each(function(){
        if($(this).children("p").text().indexOf(val) !==-1){
          $(this).show();
        }else{
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<select id="level">
  <option value="00" selected><b>Default</b></option>
  <option value="Primary">Primary</option>
  <option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
  <option value="Primary and Secondary">Primary and Secondary</option>
</select>

<select id="type">
  <option value="000" selected><b>Default</b></option>
  <option value="King">King</option>
  <option value="Queen">Queen</option>
</select>

<div class="textIc">
  <p>Primary</p>
  <p>King</p>
</div>

<div class="textIc">
  <p>Secondary</p>
</div>

<div class="textIc">
  <p>Primary and Secondary</p>
  <p>King</p>
  <p>bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>

<div class="textIc">
  <p>Primary</p>
  <p>Queen</p>
</div>


<div class="textIc">
    <p>Secondary</p>
</div>

<div class="textIc">
    <p>Primary and Secondary</p>
    <p>King</p>
    <p>bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hbx2hqos/6/) is the fiddle.

Comment: What do you mean by filtering using both of them together?

Comment: Define expected behavior in more specific terms

Comment: So, If I select Primary from first dropdown list, it will display all the divs with the word "primary" and after that If I select queen from second dropdown list, it should only display all the divs that contain the word "Primary" & "Queen"

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbx2hqos/6/

Comment: Are you looking for items that match both selectors or match either selector?

Comment: luckyape@ yes exactly. Right now the dropdown lists work individually

Comment: Do you want it to include both or just one of them?

Comment: Both. All I want is to have these 2 dropdown lists work together. Individually they are filtering the content at the moment.

So, if dropdown list 1 filters the content ABCDE individually
and dropdown list 2 filters the content DEG

if both of them are selected, the content displayed should be DE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the code that would work considering both the dropdowns.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#level').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var typeVal = $('#type').val();
    if ( val == '00'){
    if(typeVal == '000'){
        $(".textIc").show();
    }else{
      $('.textIc').each(function(){
        if($(this).children("p").text().indexOf(typeVal)!==-1){
          $(this).show();
        }else{
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
     }
    }else{

      $('.textIc').each(function(){
        if($(this).children("p").text().indexOf(val) !==-1 && (typeVal=='000' || $(this).children("p").text().indexOf(typeVal)!==-1)){
          $(this).show();
        }else{
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#type').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var levelVal = $('#level').val();
    if ( val == '000'){
        if(levelVal == '00'){
            $(".textIc").show();
      }else{
        $('.textIc').each(function(){
          if($(this).children("p").text().indexOf(levelVal)!==-1){
            $(this).show();
          }else{
            $(this).hide();
          }
        });
       }
    }else{

      $('.textIc').each(function(){
        if($(this).children("p").text().indexOf(val) !==-1 && (levelVal=='00' || $(this).children("p").text().indexOf(levelVal)!==-1)){
          $(this).show();
        }else{
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle for testing.](https://jsfiddle.net/uas163qk/)

**The basic idea** :
Check for both the dropdown values in the `change` event of each dropdown.

*Note* : The code above can be refactored to reduce the number of `if` statements. And looping through each element using `.each()` can be moved out to a separate `function()`.

Comment: I want to do this for tables. how to achieve?